# Is there any way to call the Jquery .on() within a function body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to whether is it possible to call the Jquery .on() within a function as explained below.

**JQuery code**

```
 function() {$('.progress .button:first-of-type input').val( parseInt($('.spinner  .btn:first-of-     

    type input').val());

     });
```

But I need to have a function like below it is possible?

```
 function() {$('body').on(('.progress .button:first-of-type input').val( parseInt($('.spinner  .btn:first-of-     

    type input')).val());

     });
```

Because here first-of-type that value is generated on fly. So,I need to call this .on() so that Jquery  can recognize events for the attributes created on fly.

Kindly, post your suggestions.

Comment: So you want to alter the value of a newly created input? Can't you do so when creating the input?

Comment: I want to capture the input value from multiple dynamically generated id's. While creating input only one static value is present.

Comment: Can't you bind/unbind event after creating the element?

Comment: Can you say me how to do?

Comment: Actually what you are going to do? Jqueru on() accept first argument as some event. But what you trying to pass? I can't understand your goal!

Comment: I just want Jquery to capture the dynamic value which is present infirst-of-type

Answer (score 0):

To pass the value of `$('.spinner .btn:first-of-type input')` to the other input, each time the value changes, do the following:

```
$('.spinner .btn:first-of-type input').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.progress.btn:first-of-type input').val(val);
});
```

Comment: Or make it short: `var val = $(this).val();`